# XML code for List view

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am trying to create a list view using xslt style sheet coding. I find out how write xslt with help of w3schools. But in order to write xslt coding i have to see the xml code of list view . Any one please help me, how to see the xml code of a list view in share point. currently i am using share point 2010.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62508/how-do-i-view-the-raw-xml-output-of-a-content-query-web-part , not flagging since I'm not sure, the methods are the same, but the question is slightly different

Comment: @Vinod judging from your other question (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/96603/8642), what you are missing is a deeper knowledge of how to use SPDesigner. If your goal is to write some custom XSLT for presenting the data contained in a list view, I'm quite sure you don't need to know the underlying raw XML code. All that you need is to customize the generated XSLT (which I bet you don't see when you open the list view page because it currently has the default XSLTListViewWebPart, where the generated xslt is not visible until you click on "Customize XSLT view")

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SPManager, you can navigate the SharePoint objects and see XML of ListViews, fields etc.

Here is the CodePlex page: http://spm.codeplex.com/

And here a direct link to the 2010 version: http://spm.codeplex.com/downloads/get/526736

Comment: sorry i cannot install or use any third party tools.
But thanks for your try.

Comment: That is the type of information you genereally add to your question ;) Then you will have to use for example PowerShell, to get the specific web, then list and then listview and then chack the Xsl or PropertiesXML properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx